# Rails 3.2 update attribute with nested attribute

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have model with has many relation i have added `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my model. What My problem is When i am trying to update parent record with new child added in parent which gives me an error of Record Not found . For instance: i have 1 parent record say P1 which has 2 child sayc C1,C2. Now, i am updating the value of 2 child as well as i am adding an another child in that parent. So now P1 has three child C1,C2,C3. Now when I am trying to update it using update_attributes(), it gives me error that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find UserItem with ID=0`.

How to over come with this problem?

Comment: Is UserItem the parent or the child?  Perhaps you could share some of your code?

Comment: can you please provide the code how you are updating record/ passing attributes to the update_attributes method.